# No final new line in notepad++ documents

Tags: notepad++, newlines

I'm writing bash shell scripts with Unix line endings using notepad++. However, the final line never contains a new line. I must manually create it by pressing "enter" and having a blank line in my document.

How can I configure Notepad++ to always have a newline (line feed) at the end of all lines?

Comment: What "blank line" are you referring to? My Notepad++ has no such thing. And just how is Notepad++ supposed to determine when the line is ended, unless you tap that return key?

Comment: Unix scripts in notepad++? This feels weird

Comment: I use windows and *nix at work, and so notepad++ is my preferred editor, as it has sftp and explorer plugins which I use extensively. No, not weird.

Comment: Vim adds \n to the end of every line. It doesn't need to _know_ anything

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to press Enter after the last line.
That extra blank line in Notepad++ is just visible in the editor.
It isn't really putting any data in the output file. (Besides the EOL character that you want.)

P.S. It doesn't matter whether you use Windows, Unix or Mac line-endings. The behavior of Notepad++ is the same for all three. You will have to add the "extra" blank line in order to get the EOL character appear on the line above it.